# Can I restore a PHP SESSION by its ID?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, uploadify

Im uploading files with the uploadify plugin.
the PHP SESSION is lost during upload, is there a way to restore the session?
Perhaps by its id?

Comment: What he is talking about is a common problem with flash based uploaders. They don't automatically get the cookie that identifies the session from the browser so you have send the session id manually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. You need to add an option to uploadify:

```
$('#upload').uploadify({
    'scriptData':{'session_name':"<?php echo session_id(); ?>"}
});
```

And you need to add this to your PHP:

```
<?php
session_id($_POST['session_name']);
session_start();
?>
```

Then everything will be as expected.

Comment: You need to call session_id($_POST['session_name']) before calling session_start().

Comment: @Jody you are correct, thanks. @waterschaats Since it is the correct answer, click the checkmark outline next to the question to confirm it as such.